# Is there an image service from GOES available for ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, imagery, arcims

I have an arcmap project using an arcims service from NOAA ENC (http://ocs-spatial.ncd.noaa.gov) but maybe the service is unavailable right now and I can't access to imagery...

Is there an image service from GOES available for ArcGIS?

Answer (score 2):

Check out a new attempt by NOAA to display all ENC data.

http://ocs-gis.ncd.noaa.gov/encdirect/viewer.html

This was introduced recently (Early Sept 2012) and looks a lot better than the old one! There is also talk on exposing most of these as WMS and Rest services. This will go prime-time and replace the old site sometime in Jan next year. Uptime for ENC direct has been an issue and I am not sure if the new site will alleviate this.

Your best best is to build a local solution using the freely downloadable S-57 data from NOAA and apply the rendition rules defined in S-52. This is analogous to HTML and CSS, where any map server that you host (MapServer, GeoServer, ArcGIS) can render layers you are interested in by you defining Style Layers.

Depending on what specific layers you are looking in GOES server you may be able to find them in other places or map catalogs.

Comment: I was so excited about this until I clicked the link and got nothing but a "flash must be available" page. Why do people do this nowadays is beyond me.

Comment: The upcoming NOAA site is developed in Adobe Flex - now Apache Flex, that uses flash. It is unfortunate that most of us using iOS devices are shut-out, we need a PC. What's funny is this is their next-gen attempt to revamp the older site that shows its age http://ocs-spatial.ncd.noaa.gov/encdirect/viewer.htm

Comment: Doing it in Flex shows a very poor technical choice on their part. *None* of the functionality I saw in that site cannot be done with plain HTML. It is as if I decided to revamp the GIS StackExchange and write it using classic ASP.